# Как проверить что сайт доступен для пользователей из китая?

Tags: http, браузер, веб-служба

Как проверить что сайт доступен для пользователей из Китая?

Comment: Быстрый гуглёж показал такой сервис: [blockedinchina](http://www.blockedinchina.net/)

Comment: LEQADA, спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Поезжайте в Китай, проверяйте на месте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://check-host.net/

Там выбираете http и вводите адрес.
В списке есть Гонконг.

Второй 
https://ping-admin.ru/free_test/

Там вводите сайт, и ставите галку на Китай.

Comment: еще стоит рассмотреть [классику host-tracker](http://www.host-tracker.com/) у него побольше точек проверки

Answer (score 1):

Используйте прокси-сервера, например
http://spys.ru/free-proxy-list/CN/